# Evaluating the sum of a sequence given the first term, last term and difference

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I was wondering whether the method i use to get the sum here was right. I was given this question in a multiple choice section and i honestly cant see where i went wrong. I was wondering whether i did indeed do something wrong or if the answers provided were wrong.

$$a_1 = 1, \text{common difference} = 3, \text{last term }= 100$$

So firstly I began by using the information above to get the Recurrence Relation which i worked out to be

$$an = 1 + (n-1)3$$

now as I understand you need to use the sum equation $\frac12n(a+l)$ to find the sum.

The one thing I am struggling with is finding n as it tells me $a_0 = 1$, although i know the last term is $100$, I cant use this to find $n$ number for the sum.

So I tried setting

$$100 = 1 + (n-1)3$$

to solve for $n$ and so i got

\begin{align} 100 &= 1 + 3n - 3\\
        100&= -2 + 3n\\
        100 + 2 &=3n\\
        102 &= 3n\\
        \frac{102}3 &= n\\
        34 &= n
\end{align}

using

$ u0 = 1$ and $u_34 = 100$ with the sum equation

$$\frac12(34)(1+100) = 1717$$

so the sum I reached was $1717$

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems fine. $1717$ is the right answer.

I wrote a short [code](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_p0m2CQlmIp7vS4H.py)  to verify your answer too.

Comment: Thanks. Im guessing it just an error on her part considering one of the answers listed was 1700 so il send her an email notifying her that she may have made a mistake setting the questions.